# Install DXA 2.1.0 in Tridion Sites 9

Tags: dxa, sites-9, dxa-2.1

We had installed DXA 2.1.0 Resolver in tridion sites 9 but CME is not loading properly. It is working fine after comment out below elements in system.config.

```
<editor name='DXAResolver'>
      <installpath>C:\Program Files (x86)\SDL Web\web\WebUI\Editors</installpath>
      <configuration>Configuration\DXAResolver.Editor.config</configuration>
      <vdir>DxaResolver</vdir>
    </editor>
<model name='DXAResolver'>
      <installpath>C:\Program Files (x86)\SDL Web\web\WebUI\Editors</installpath>
      <configuration>Configuration\DXAResolver.Model.config</configuration>
      <vdir>DxaResolver</vdir>
</model>
```

[image]

we used below script for execution.
    .\cms-customresolver.ps1 -extensionTargetFolder "C:\Program Files (x86)\SDL Web\web\WebUI" -cmSiteName "SDL Web"

Please let us know what went wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you installed the DXA Resolver UI Extension in `%TRIDION_HOME%/web/WebUI`.  This is known to not work properly on Sites 9.

See https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v11/GUID-B2394627-794C-4AF0-BDF3-C5B3A5398327

If you specify another location for `extensionTargetFolder` (or just use the default location), it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you @Rick , Please let us know rollback steps. Is it OK if we move Editor(Commands,Configuration,Constants,Resources,Themes,Views and web.config) and Model folder(Client,Configuration,Resources,Services and web.config) of DXA Resolver to other locations and point to new location in system.config.